# Share dynamic data in memory between gunicorn workers

Tags: python, django, tornado, gunicorn, uwsgi

I have a web app written in Django/Celery/Postgres/Gunicorn/Nginx.

The app allows performing scientific simulations to the user. These simulations can take from 5 seconds to 5 minutes. Regular requests and quick simulations are done with the standard blocking paradigm while long simulations are run in the background (some are even submitted to several AWS Lambda instances in parallel) by celery and then the client is updated by a WebSocket.

When a client logs in and opens one of his projects, a Simulation object is initialized and stored in a dict as {user:Simulation}. Initializing this Simulation object can take about 10 seconds so it is only done at the beginning. Every time the user interacts with his simulation on the client side, a particular view queries the Simulation object to the global dict and applies any changes, retrieves data, saves the simulation, runs the simulation, etc.

The problem with this approach is that it only works with 1 gunicorn worker since additional workers do not have access to the Simulation objects inside the global dict. Moreover, it is not possible to pre-load the objects since they are constantly changed by the user.

What is the best approach to work with such global dynamic object, that is too expensive to be re-initialized with every request ?

Comment: I have been investigating and gunicorn does not support sharing data between workers. However, it seems possible in uWSGI. If a user with experience in uWSGI can confirm this and give me some hints, I'll try to implement a solution and post it here.

Comment: I found this non-wsgi framework which might also be a good option: https://www.tornadoweb.org

Comment: Why not just write the data to the database shared across workers? Alternatively, why not a memcache to store those objects?

Comment: I need the Simulation object to be in memory in order to access its methods with every request. Storing it in a database would mean that I'd need to re-initialize every time the object, which takes several seconds.
The memcache approach might work if gunicorn workers have access to it. I'll test it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a memcache here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#memcached

The basic interface is set(key, value, timeout) and get(key):

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)
>>> cache.get('my_key')
'hello, world!'
```

Comment: how about a ramdisk? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive
creates a local file share that is actually represented in RAM, then you can read and write to it at blazing speeds; serialize your simulation object and write it to the ramdisk and then each worker just reads it

Comment: This approach actually works. My issue is that I cannot pickle the Simulation object so I'll have to tweak it a bit.